# play compile error Cannot access term libs in value <root>.api. The current classpath may be missing a definition for <root>.api.libs,

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3

I have a play application named `myApp` and in which I have a sub-project named `searching`. I want to access the model class that is present in myApp(root project) in my sub-project `searching`. Then I decided to create another sbt independent project named `common` and in that project I put the model classes and run the package on it. It created a jar for me then i dropped this jar in my play's sub-project `searching` lib directory. 
Now the problem is when I am trying to compile my play project along with sub-project play is giving me that error:

```
myApp>activator
[info] Compiling 45 Scala sources to /media/sara/682AA7A32AA76D2E/study/project/Searching/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] bad symbolic reference to <root>.play encountered in class file 'Delete.class'.
[error] Cannot access term play in package <root>. The current classpath may be
[error] missing a definition for <root>.play, or Delete.class may have been compiled against a version that's
[error] incompatible with the one found on the current classpath.
[error] bad symbolic reference to play.api encountered in class file 'Delete.class'.
[error] Cannot access term api in value play. The current classpath may be
[error] missing a definition for play.api, or Delete.class may have been compiled against a version that's
[error] incompatible with the one found on the current classpath.
[error] bad symbolic reference to <root>.api.libs encountered in class file 'Delete.class'.
[error] Cannot access term libs in value <root>.api. The current classpath may be
[error] missing a definition for <root>.api.libs, or Delete.class may have been compiled against a version that's
[error] incompatible with the one found on the current classpath.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last testSearching/compile:compile for the full output.
[error] (testSearching/compile:compile) scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeError: bad symbolic reference to <root>.libs.json encountered in class file 'Delete.class'.
[error] Cannot access term json in value <root>.libs. The current classpath may be
[error] missing a definition for <root>.libs.json, or Delete.class may have been compiled against a version that's
[error] incompatible with the one found on the current classpath.
[error] Total time: 14 s, completed Oct 20, 2015 1:29:37 PM
```

I am using play 2.3.8; my play project `myApp` has following directory structure

```
-app
--models
---Delete.scala
-Searcing
-src/main/scala
-------Demo.scala
-lib
--common.jar
```

here is the code of Delete.scala

```
package models

//import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.api.libs.json._

@SerialVersionUID(1)
case class Delete( var deleteStatusInt : Int = 0 , var deleteReasonInt : Int = 0) extends Serializable {

  def getDeleteStatusInt =DeleteStatus(deleteStatusInt)
  def getDeleteReasonInt =DeleteReason(deleteReasonInt)

}

object Delete {
  implicit val deleteFormat = Json.format[Delete]
}
```

and Demo.scala is not using Delete.Scala code

here is the build file of myApp project

```
name := """myApp"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val project = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
    .aggregate(searching)
    .dependsOn(searching)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

fork in run := true

javaOptions in run ++= Seq("-J-Xms1G", "-J-Xmx2G")

val appDependencies = Seq(
  // Add your project dependencies here,
  "org.scalatestplus" %% "play" % "1.2.0" % "test"
)

lazy val searching = project


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(""org.apache.lucene" % "lucene-expressions" % "4.10.4",
                "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.6",
                )
```

here is the build file of searching sub-project

```
name := """searching"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.lucene" % "lucene-expressions" % "4.10.4",
                "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.6")
```

and the independent sbt project I created, Has the following structure

```
common
-src/main/scala
--models
---Delete.scala
```

and here is the code of Delete.scala

```
package models

//import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.api.libs.json._

@SerialVersionUID(1)
case class Delete( var deleteStatusInt : Int = 0 , var deleteReasonInt : Int = 0) extends Serializable {

  def getDeleteStatusInt =DeleteStatus(deleteStatusInt)
  def getDeleteReasonInt =DeleteReason(deleteReasonInt)

}

object Delete {
  implicit val deleteFormat = Json.format[Delete]
}
```

here is the build.sbt for the common project

```
name := "common"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

organization      := "models"

scalaVersion      := "2.11.1"

publishMavenStyle := true

libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.lucene" % "lucene-expressions" % "4.10.4",
                                //"com.typesafe.play" % "play-json_2.11" % "2.3.8",
                                "com.typesafe.play" % "play_2.11" % "2.3.8",
                "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.6"
                )
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this issue by adding play library dependency in `searching` build.sbt file

```
name := """searching"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.lucene" % "lucene-expressions" % "4.10.4",
"com.typesafe.play" % "play_2.11" % "2.3.8",
                "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.6")
```

the  problem was occurring because i did not add the same libraries as used in the project whose jar is been used so adding those libraries in `seraching` project build.sbt solves the issue